Diagnostics UI not updating after empty code action
How to configure Neovim to re-render the diagnostics UI after a code action that does not update the buffer?

The LSP server sends code actions list to Neovim client
one of the code actions does not update the buffer (it's for ignoring the error)

The code action sends the new diagnostics list using (textDocument/publishDiagnostics) to Neovim

Now the UI does not change unless I update the buffer manually


NOTE

the LSP is a custom LSP
it's a bug in Neovim


Welcome to [vi.se]! You might want to give more details into what specifically you're experiencing, what LSP server are you using (or this happens with every LSP server), which specific actions are not updating the diagnostics UI? If you consider this might be a bug in Neovim, consider reporting it by opening an issue at their bug tracker: https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues

local function reset(client_id)
    vim.validate({ client_id = { client_id, 'n' } })

    local client = vim.lsp.get_client_by_id(client_id)
    local server_id = vim.tbl_get((client or {}).server_capabilities, 'diagnosticProvider', 'identifier')

    local pull_ns_name = string.format('vim.lsp.%s.%d.%s', client and client.name or 'unknown', client_id,
        server_id or 'nil')
    local push_ns_name = string.format('vim.lsp.%s.%d', client and client.name or 'unknown', client_id)

    local pull_ns = vim.api.nvim_create_namespace(pull_ns_name)
    local push_ns = vim.api.nvim_create_namespace(push_ns_name)

    vim.diagnostic.reset(push_ns)
    vim.diagnostic.reset(pull_ns)
end


vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd('FileType', {
    callback = function()
        vim.lsp.start({
            handlers = {
                ["textDocument/publishDiagnostics"] = function(_, result, ctx, config)
-- if no diagnostics is sent, reset all 
                    if #result.diagnostics == 0 then
                        reset(ctx.client_id)
                    else
-- else just let neovim handle it 
                        vim.lsp.diagnostic.on_publish_diagnostics(_, result, ctx, config)
                    end
                end
            }
        })
    end,
})


Welcome to Vim! Thank fir your contribution! Maybe could you add some explanation to your solution for the other to understand better your solution :-)
